# 16x2 LCD showing blocks under text

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

I have a LCD connected to a Arduino Mega 2560 using the instructions in `LiquidCrystal` library. It is not the first time I am using a 16x2 LCD but I never have encountered a problem like this. When I first connect the Arduino Mega to PC I see a row of blocks in first row of LCD which looks like normal to me. Then after that there is a block of white under each character.

Now I have searched a little and saw whole blocks which was due to bad soldering or bad wiring or etc. I have checked soldering and wiring twice. used 3 different LCD's and 2 different Mega's and it is still the same.

Any suggestions?

These are the images from when I turn it on:

[image: image1] [image: image2]

**[SOLVED] Update :**

Looks like the POT was broken and did not respond the way it used to. So i replaced `V0` with a 2.5k resistor and connected them to GND.
Here is the updated image :
 [image]

Comment: can you please post an update later with adjusted contrast which looks fine?

Comment: @user1306322 updated with image

Comment: My LCD display shows gibberish character. How do I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The row of white blocks is what you get before the screen's initialized. It's normal.

The shadow behind the characters is because you have the contrast turned up too high. Adjust it down a little.

Answer (score 1):

If your contrast is not adjustable by a pot, there's a resistor that goes on the contrast pin that controls the level of contrast, which is what is causing the dark blocks.

Comment: Some LCD modules also have software contrast adjustment. Read the datasheet